# Is it possible to add a new Key/Value to the beginning of the dictionary instead of the back

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

if I have a dictionary: `d = {1:a}`, and I want to add a new key and value to the beginning of the dictionary, instead of adding it to the back, is that possible? For example, it would be like:

```
dictionary = {1:a}
dictionary[2] = 'b'
print(d)

>>> {2:b, 1:a}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the dictionary a `collections.OrderedDict` object instead and use its [`move_to_end`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.move_to_end) method to move the new key to the beginning of the dict with the `last=False` argument:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dictionary = OrderedDict({1: 'a'})
dictionary[2] = 'b'
dictionary.move_to_end(2, last=False)
print(dict(dictionary))
```

This outputs:

```
{2: 'b', 1: 'a'}
```